# Using a large drawing tablet as a monitor

Tags: drawing-tablet, hardware, monitor

I wonder if I could use a larger drawing tablet (e.g., a 22" or 24" model) as a regular monitor or if there are drawbacks why one shouldn't do it. I've seen that people are using it similar to a monitor when drawing, but I do not know if they use it as a monitor when doing other things as well and what the drawbacks may be.

The advantage is, that it would save space on the desk or moving the tablet around when it can be used as a monitor and only needs to be tilted to start drawing.

For the disadvantages I think that many monitors are better optimized for movies and gaming and everything that needs a high/steady framerate, but I wonder if it wouldn't be as good as a usual monitor for web browsing and office work.

The hardware aspects would be if such tablets are made to be used for longer durations or if they wear off faster than other hardware.

The usability aspects include if the viewing angle is optimized for tilting it when drawing and if the angle is smaller, but I think some display technologies have small viewing angles as well and drawing tablets seem to often use IPS that has good properties there. Other factors may be about the contrast and colors, but they are probably only better (calibrated).

Yet another aspect would be application software. In the comments was mentioned that some programs use another UI when the display is detected to have touch capabilities, which would only be appropriate for drawing and not for other work.

The particular model I am wondering about the XP-PEN Artist 22R, which looks like it has a stand to be used vertically and also has a VESA mount on the backside so that it may be suitable as a monitor. It also as IPS display technology.

Comment: This is too close to a hardware question, but these are generally off-topic here. You are asking us to speculate on the drawbacks of using a specific piece of hardware regarding its use as a monitor and possible damage or degradation caused by doing so. I don't think this counts as a graphic design question. Really sorry about that. Perhaps more suited to [Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) although, I'm not certain if this would be on topic there either. Perhaps you could even contact the manufacturer.

Comment: @BillyKerr I am more asking about experience from graphics designers than the actual hardware details. I don't care why the hardware may degrade or be less usable, but I care about if someone tried to use a drawing tablet in that way and it worked out for them or not. If someone would explain me the technical details about the techniques used in monitors and tablets it would be interesting on a technical level, but the question is more about the high-level problem if such a setup would be useful or has drawbacks. I can try to rephrase the question a bit.

Comment: "If someone would explain me the technical details about the techniques used in monitors and tablets" - but that would be a hardware question though. Again it's off-topic. Sorry

Comment: @BillyKerr I've said that would be interesting (to me, but out of scope here) and the question is about the high-level problem. I now edited the question a bit to read less technical.

Comment: Usability aspects are kind of subjective - again not a good fit for GDSE. We also tend to avoid answering questions which generate opinions rather than facts.  This is a tough one and I get where you are coming from, but I don't know if it's answerable. What you may find useful, someone else may not.  Maybe try it, see how it goes, but ultimately check with the manufacturer if you think it will cause some damage.

Comment: One drawback that I’ve heard from others (but have no idea about myself) is that apps like Illustrator and InDesign will force you into their ‘touch-enabled UI’ if you’re using a touch-enabled screen, which I assume a tablet would be. A lot of people really, really hate that UI, but it seems there’s no way to turn it off.

Comment: Can you browse the web, read emails, do "general office work" on an iPad or similar?? There's your answer. I'd second the comment from @JanusBahsJacquet above - I have a touch-capable (non-screen) intuos tablet. My largest issue is when some apps see the touch, even when I have it turned off in the tablet software. I'd also point out that if you don't already have a touch screen for drawing/illustration, you may dislike using a touch screen for such a thing. I find always having to either "hover" my wrist above the surface, or wear a smudge glove to draw on a touchscreen less workable for me.

Comment: After I added something about your comments to the question. Maybe you want to make them an answer and we can use the question to collect advantages and disadvantages in the answers? I would for example not have thought about the programs using the touch enabled UI.

Comment: While relative to Graphic Design, I'm not certain how on topic it is. Primarily because responses are really more opinion-based than anything. There can be no "definitive" answer here and StackExchange isn't really about "general advice" or "opinions". (and note the smudge gloves on [X-Pen's site](https://www.xp-pen.com/product/541.html) `:)` (I've never used or beed exposed to X-Pen. All I know is Wacom.)